# Can someone explain to me in simple terms what Passenger is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I was researching to set up my linux (ubuntu) vps for rails. And almost all of the guides I've read tells me to install passenger. But none of the guides explain what it is (atleast not in simple terms). So I was wondering if someone could explain in simple terms what exactly passenger is.

I'm trying to set up my VPS so I can easily push code to it from git, and deploy my app (Easy as heroku?) Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried their website? http://www.modrails.com/

Comment: Then you shouldn't need to be asking this question. The docs explain in simple terms what Passenger does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your web server (apache/nginx) serves HTTP requests for files, like stylesheets and images. But, it doesn't know how to process programming code. In PHP, for example, you have to enable mod_php to allow PHP to run.

Passenger is to ruby/rails what mod_php is to PHP.

Your web server still serves static files, but has passenger run your ruby code.

Comment: So what makes it better than the rails default? webrick?

Comment: Webrick is only for development. It can't handle more than one concurrent request, and it has certain other limitations. Mongrel (which used to be a common choice) also can't handle multiple concurrent requests, but it can easily be clustered. However, the clustering's a bit of a pain because of the multiple instances. Passenger, OTOH, makes Apache or Nginx serve Rails about as easily as PHP. It takes care of spawning and killing extra server processes -- just set it and forget it. This is all clearly explained on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Passenger usually works with Apache/nginx.

Passenger does the dynamic things, Apache/nginx serves 
 static files and helps passenger to communicate with user-agents

Answer (score -1):

mod passenger or phusion passenger is a module to deploy ruby on rails application in nginx or apache . Currently you must be using either web brick or mongrel. using mod passenger you can have the full power of nginx or apache at your disposal,

Comment: That's so vague and inaccurate that I don't even know where to start correcting it.